# Converting C++ to PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I had an assignment for which I need to list the first 100 Prime Numbers in PowerShell Script. So I coded using C++ and try to convert to PowerShell Script. And the output in PowerShell was not what I am expected.

Note: I am new to PowerShell. Just start learning since past 2 days

I tried to understand the PowerShell syntax and convert it

C++:

```
int i, j, count = 1, b = 0;

for ( i = 3; i > 0; ++i ) 
{
    for ( j = 2; j <= i / 2; ++j )
    {
        if ( i % j == 0 )   
        {
            b = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( b == 0 )
    {
        cout << i << endl;
        count++;
    }
    b = 0;
    if ( count == 101 )
        break;
}
```

PowerShell:

```
$i
$j
$count = 0
$prime = 0

for ( $i = 3; $i -lt 0; ++$i ) 
{
    for ( $j = 2; $j -le $i / 2; ++$j )    
    {
        if ( $i % $j -eq 0 )    
        {
            $prime = 1   
            break    
        }
    }

    if ( $prime -eq 0 )    
    {
        Write-Host("$i 'r 'n")    
        $count++ 
    }
    $prime = 0    
    if ( $count -eq 101 )
    {
        break    
    }
}
```

I expect the result will be first 100 prime numbers from 3 to 547

But I get 3 2 from PowerShell.

Any advice is welcomed. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.

`>` is `-gt`, you used `-lt` in your script.

```
$i = 0
$j = 0
$count = 0
$prime = 0

for ($i = 3; $i -gt 0; ++$i) {
    for ($j = 2; $j -le $i / 2; ++$j) {
        if ($i % $j -eq 0 ) {
            $prime = 1
            break
        }
    }

    if ($prime -eq 0) {
        Write-Output $i
        $count++
    }
    $prime = 0
    if ($count -eq 100) {
        break
    }
}
```